# How does navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition get your latitude and longitude?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, ip, navigator

Does it extract that information from your IP address? If not, then how does it get your lat and long coordinates?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Answer (score 1):

From [geotargetly](https://geotargetly.com/html5-geolocation-api):

"HTML5 geolocation detects latitude and longitude coordinates by using the device's GPS (if available on the device) or the device's mobile/WIFI signal (if GPS is not available. The mobile/WIFI signals are triangulated to work out the latitude and longitude."